# How to extract the text from PDF document

Tags: c#

I have one pdf document which has links. I need to get link title.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Sow

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iText PDF library to read the PDF file contents.. and get the text,links or there values from the PDF file. you can get the library from [here](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/)!